# Send signal from iPhone to a microcontroller

Tags: ios, networking, microcontroller

I feel like this should be a basic and easy task but I'm struggling to find resources out there to help. 
I want to send integer values to an ip address on the same network.
I believe the best way to achieve this is by an UDP message? 
The receiving device is connected via wifi.

How would this be achieved in an iPhone app using objective c?

Comment: Using what protocol? How is the microcontroller connected to the network and what protocols can it listen to?

Comment: Not sure, I'm a complete noob when it comes to networking, i will be using the ARM Cortex Discovery stm32f4 if that helps?  http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/PF252419?sc=internet/evalboard/product/252419.jsp

Comment: I don't know anything about microcontrollers I'm afraid... your first task would be to find out how exactly you want to receive values on that specific device (using what protocol). The rest is likely easy to Google (using a query like `<name of protocol> send ios`)

Comment: okay I will look further into it, thanks for the assist!

Comment: well working from the iphone side your primary choices are wifi/network or bluetooth.   Your microcontroller board has neither.  But you should have one or many uarts, with which you can connect to a bluetooth board or an ethernet/wifi board.   An esp8266 for example.  For the wifi side both have to have an access point and in some way those two or that one access point has to give you access to a network that connects the two.  if in the same place on the same access point then no problem.  bluetooth you have to pair and be close enough.

Comment: you might look at the simblee as it has an arm you can program and bluetooth, so maybe you dont need the other microcontroller.  Likewise the esp8266 has a non-arm 32 bit risc processor that can be reprogrammed so you could also have wifi and a processor.  you can go with the next thing co C.H.I.P for $9 which has wifi, likely major overkill on the processing side, and power consumption, but we dont know what you are after.  raspberry pi for that matter some of them have wired ethernet.

Comment: and of course depending on what you want to send you may need to write an iphone app (or maybe just a web interface will do).

Comment: Yeah i have the wifi adapter for the ARM chip, and the iPhone is connected to the same network, all i need to do is the code for the iPhone app to send the data. After looking into it more i believe i have to send a UDP message. Here is a youtube video of a similar task, however i would like to achieve this with an iPhone. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQnJ59WELxM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lot of ways to achieve what you need (for example you could run web server on your Discovery board and connect from iPhone, run telnet server, open socket connection etc.).

But since you've stated that UDP transfer is what you want, I will recommend you to take look on [UDPEcho](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/UDPEcho/Introduction/Intro.html) example or even better [AcynchUDPSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) class which provides all functionality that you need:

> Native objective-c, fully self-contained in one class. No need to muck
>   around with low-level sockets. This class handles everything for you.
>
> Full delegate support. Errors, send completions, receive completions,
>   and disconnections all result in a call to your delegate method.
>
> Queued non-blocking send and receive operations, with optional
>   timeouts. You tell it what to send or receive, and it handles
>   everything for you. Queueing, buffering, waiting and checking errno -
>   all handled for you automatically.
>
> Support for IPv4 and IPv6. Automatically send/recv using IPv4 and/or
>   IPv6. No more worrying about multiple sockets.

It is easy to add it to your project using cocoapods and you will find nice examples on git repo.

I would recommend you to start with UDP broadcast.

Hope it helps...